# I am skeptical about the redirection operation of below example

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I was successful in redirecting the error message to a text file in the below process:

```
  $ ls + 2>err.txt
  $ cat err.txt
  ls: cannot access +: No such file or directory
```

But when I try to attempt the same process with echo command it shows different output and unable to redirect the error message to a text file.

```
$ echo )hey 2>err.txt
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
```

Comment: here the bash syntax is broken.  It couldn't parse beyond ")" to get the redirection.

Comment: Use `echo ")hey" 2> err.txt`. But note that `)hey` goes through stdout, and you're redirecting the stderr stream. The bracket is a reserved symbol in bash. To make `)` part of your output string, enclose the string in `"`.

Comment: that should be `echo ")hey" 2>err.txt`

Comment: This has nothing to do with redirection; simply syntax errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example, it is the `ls` command that produces the error message that is written to `err.txt`.

In your second command, you are expecting the following to happen:

1. The line is successfully parsed
2. `bash` opens `err.txt` for the standard error of `echo`
3. `echo` tries to output `)hey`
4. `echo` encounters an error
5. The error message is written to `err.txt`.

However, `bash` never makes it past the first line, so none of 2 through 5 ever happens. Instead, the shell immediately stops processing the line and prints the error message to its *own* standard error.